# Parametric equations of the tangent line to a curve

Tags: calculus, parametric, tangent-line

I am studying my for my midterm and have been having troubles with a specific problem. I found the solution for it here, https://socratic.org/questions/the-surface-z-xsqrt-x-y-intersects-the-plane-y-3-along-a-curve-c-how-do-you-find, but I am unsure of how the line is being parameterized. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure where you are stuck, but usually given a point, let's say   $P_o = (x_o, y_o, z_o)$ and vector (aka direction vector) $\vec{v} = (a,b,c)$ then you are interested in all points $P = (x,y,z)$ satisfying 
$$ P-P_o = t\vec{v} \quad\text{for some}\quad t \in \mathbb R$$
This give us
$$ x = x_o + at \\y = y_o + bt \\ z = z_o + ct$$